# Numpy operations are not valid with groupby. Use .groupby(...).mean() instead, which is what I did

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, mean

I want to get the average of each of the two first columns of the following dataframe `people_preferences` according to their segments `Segment`.

```
      Fun|Not-Fun              Pro-garden|Pro-home      Segment
0                          NaN                NaN       cats
1                          NaN                NaN       cats
2                         -1.0                NaN       cats

...                        ...                ...        ...
4570                      -1.0               -1.0       dogs
4571                      -1.0                1.0       dogs
4572                      -1.0                1.0       dogs
```

So I tried `people_preferences.groupby('Segment', as_index=False).mean( skipna = True)` but it returned: `UnsupportedFunctionCall: numpy operations are not valid with groupby. Use .groupby(...).mean() instead`

Here is the full error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnsupportedFunctionCall                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-489-f8da6e73c33c> in <module>
     48 pairs = list(itertools.combinations(df_features.columns, 2))
     49 
---> 50 [plot_mean(pair[0],pair[1]) for pair in pairs]
     51 
     52 fig = px.scatter(df_features, x=columns_x, y=columns_y)

<ipython-input-489-f8da6e73c33c> in <listcomp>(.0)
     48 pairs = list(itertools.combinations(df_features.columns, 2))
     49 
---> 50 [plot_mean(pair[0],pair[1]) for pair in pairs]
     51 
     52 fig = px.scatter(df_features, x=columns_x, y=columns_y)

<ipython-input-489-f8da6e73c33c> in plot_mean(column_x, column_y)
     23         people_preferences = df_features[[column_x,column_y,'Segment']]
     24         print(people_preferences)
---> 25         print(people_preferences.groupby('Segment', as_index=False).mean( skipna = True))
     26         # parties.append('PEOPLE')
     27         dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=parties_x, y=parties_y, parties = parties))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in mean(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1200         Name: B, dtype: float64
   1201         """
-> 1202         nv.validate_groupby_func("mean", args, kwargs, ["numeric_only"])
   1203         try:
   1204             return self._cython_agg_general(

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\numpy\function.py in validate_groupby_func(name, args, kwargs, allowed)
    375                 "numpy operations are not valid "
    376                 "with groupby. Use .groupby(...)."
--> 377                 "{func}() instead".format(func=name)
    378             )
    379         )
```

Comment: I think it is bug, `skipna = True` with `mean` per groups

Comment: this might be relevant: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19806

Comment: `df.groupby('Segment').mean()` works as expected. You don't need `skipna=True`.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in pandas. See [mean with skipna either True or False on groupby gives error](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32696)

#### Workaround

- Use the [pandas.aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) instead

```py
# define helper function
def custom_mean(df):
    return df.mean(skipna=True)

# instead of 
df.mean(skipna=True)

# use 
df.agg(custom_mean)
```

*(Note: Might be that the `skipna=True` is the default for the `pandas.mean()`, although for some reason the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) show default value of `skipna=None`)*

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand correctly the problem, but, to solve the issue (not particularly the error), you shouldn't have trouble using: `df.groupby(['Segment'])['Fun|Not-Fun','Pro-garden|Pro-home'].mean()` because the default behaviour is to `skipna=True` for `mean()`. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
a = {'a':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'data':[np.nan,10,20,20,30,10],'data_2':[10,20,30,np.nan,10,20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)

print(df.groupby('a',as_index=False)['data','data_2'].mean())
```

Output:

```
   a  data  data_2
0  1  15.0    20.0
1  2  20.0    15.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, which in my case I could get round by not trying to add the output of the operation as a new column in my existing dataframe. Rather, I ran

```
by_row_index = data.groupby(data.index)
data_means   = by_row_index.mean()
```

creating a new dataframe with the appropriate means that I could then plot from.